# What are the pros and cons of reusing an AFHTTPRequestOperationManager?

Tags: ios, objective-c, api

We're making calls to an API to get JSON data using `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`.

Currently, we are instantiating a new `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` for each request. We're considering instantiating just a single `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` and reusing it across requests.

What are the trade-offs?

Comment: I'd go for a singleton implementation. Especially if all your requests go to single web domain.

Comment: @rokjarc why would you go with a singleton implementation, especially for a request to a single domain?

Comment: Singleton in this case helps to keep the code a bit more clean: no need to keep a bunch of references across the app (or keeping one in `AppDelegate`). I mentioned the 'single domain' because of the `initWithBaseURL:` constructor. Property `baseURL` is readonly. You might want to migrate to 3.x (`AFHTTPSessionManager`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several reasons why AFHTTPRequestOperationManager per domain is a handy pattern:

1) You save the resources of creating a new manager for each request which can create significant memory pressure

2) Having just one reference to a manager allows you to easily manage all the network requests in your app. For example, when a user logs out you may want to cancel all requests. With just one manager you can easily access the operation queue and cancel them all at once.

3) Related to #2, having one instance allows you to manage the configuration for all your requests at once. For instance adding authorization headers or configuring custom parsers. These could of course be done before every request but it adds unnecessary complexity.

Comment: 1 and 2 are strong points. Reason 3 is not as strong: before, we had a single method that created, configured and returned a new AFHTTPRequestOperationManager, so all this logic was in one place. In response to your (excellent) answer, I just added the `static` keyword and an `if(!manager){/*config*/} check.